# How can I de-obfuscate this Javascript code..are you beast enough?

Tags: javascript, facebook, obfuscation, facebook-javascript-sdk, deobfuscation

Ive been searching for hours to de obfuscate this facebook script code , tried some programs and failed , asked on several forums no one knows . if you think your a beast and could do it give it a shot ..thanks :)

```
<div style="display:none"><script id="_waue6n">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('p b=["\\d\\f\\e\\h\\h","\\K\\f\\G\\A\\I\\H\\f\\v\\e\\i\\j\\d","\\k\\l\\v","\\m\\r\\d\\k","\\d\\l\\s\\t\\m\\g","\\l\\s\\c\\e\\g\\c\\y\\h\\c\\f\\c\\i\\g","\\e\\d\\w\\i\\l","\\d\\s\\l","\\k\\g\\g\\m\\L\\o\\o\\z\\t\\n\\j\\c\\g\\d\\u\\e\\f\\r\\i\\j\\u\\r\\d\\o\\d\\f\\e\\h\\h\\u\\B\\d","\\e\\m\\m\\c\\i\\n\\C\\k\\t\\h\\n","\\k\\c\\e\\n","\\j\\c\\g\\y\\h\\c\\f\\c\\i\\g\\d\\D\\w\\E\\e\\j\\F\\e\\f\\c"];p q=q||[];q[b[3]]([b[0],b[1],b[2]]);(J(){p a=x[b[5]](b[4]);a[b[6]]=M;a[b[7]]=b[8];x[b[N]](b[O])[0][b[9]](a)})();',51,51,'|||||||||||_0xea67|x65|x73|x61|x6D|x74|x6C|x6E|x67|x68|x63|x70|x64|x2F|var|_wau|x75|x72|x69|x2E|x76|x79|document|x45|x77|x7A|x6A|x43|x42|x54|x4E|x33|x66|x39|function|x30|x3A|true|11|10'.split('|'),0,{}))</script></div>
```

Comment: Why not run it and see what the `eval()` returns?

Comment: A tool like http://jsbeautifier.org/ will get you some of the way.

Comment: couldn't you just run it? If this were Perl, I'd be wary, but a sandboxed JS interpreter seems safe enough.

Comment: This should shed some light on it for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/sEzKg/1/ (in a nutshell it is adding a script tag that points at `http://widgets.amung.us/small.js` to the document's `head` section).

Answer (score 5):

That's not all the javascript or it wasn't copied correctly, however, it looks like it's using Dean Edwards' Javascript Packer to obfuscate the code. A link to the coder and decoder is here: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

As a general rule of thumb for unobfuscating the code you can usually replace the opening eval() with either document.write() or alert().

Anyways, best of luck!